# Formatting consecutive numbers

Tags: python, int, format

I'm trying to format a list of integers with Python and I'm having a few difficulties achieving what I'd like.

Input is a sorted list of Integers:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
```

I would like it the output to be a String looking like this:

```
outputString = "1-3, 6, 8-9"
```

So far all I managed to achieve is this:

```
outputString = "1-2-3, 6, 8-9"
```

I'm having trouble to tell my code to ignore a Int if it was already consecutive.

Here is my code so far:

```
def format(l):
    i = 0
    outputString = str(l[i])
    for x in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i + 1] == l[i]+1 :
            outputString += '-' + str(l[i+1])
        else :
            outputString += ', ' + str(l[i+1])
        i = i + 1
    return outputString
```

Thanks for your help and insights :)

Comment: I was dealing with the same problem some time ago. Unfortunately I cannot find the code now. But I remember that it was decided that "8, 9" is more human readable than "8-9", so we were using the first-last notation only for 3 and more consecutive integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `count` from `itertools` module like this way:

**Edit:**

Thanks to `@asongtoruin` comment. For removing duplicates from the input you can use: `sorted(set(a))`.

```
from itertools import groupby, count

a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
clustered = [list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(a), lambda n, c = count(): n-next(c))]

for k in clustered:
    if len(k) > 1:
        print("{0}-{1}".format(k[0], k[-1]))
    else:
        print("{0}".format(k[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
1-3
6
8-9
```

Or maybe you can do something like this in order to have a pretty output:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

a = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
clustered = [list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(a), lambda n, c = count(): n-next(c))]
out = ", ".join(["{0}-{1}".format(k[0], k[-1]) if len(k) > 1 else "{0}".format(k[0]) for k in clustered ])

print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
1-3, 6, 8-9
```

**Update:**

I'm guessing, using itertools modules may confuse many `Python`'s new developers. This is why i decided to rewrite the same solution without importing any package and trying to show what `groupby` and `count` are doing behind the scenes:

```
def count(n=0, step=1):
    """Return an infinite generator of numbers"""
    while True:
        n += step
        yield n


def concat(lst):
    """Group lst elements based on the result of elm - next(_count)"""
    _count, out = count(), {}
    for elm in sorted(lst):
        c = elm - next(_count)
        if c in out:
            out[c].append(elm)
        else:
            out[c] = [elm]
    return out


def pretty_format(dct):
    for _, value in dct.items():
        if len(value) > 1:
            yield '{}-{}'.format(value[0], value[-1])
        else:
            yield '{}'.format(value[0])


lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
dct = concat(lst)
formatted = list(pretty_format(dct))
print(formatted)
```

**Output:**

```
['1-3', '6', '8-9']
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo i'm updating my answer

Comment: Updated, see now :-)

Comment: Neat answer. Is it worth using `sorted(set(a))` to account for possible duplicates?

Comment: Yes of course. I just used the OP input in this answer. But you're right for general purpose your suggestion is right. I'll add it to my answer :-) thanks.

Comment: Welcome @juanpa.arrivillaga, you can post your answer too, maybe you have something new to add.

Comment: Never used itertools before, I'll definitely give it a try ! Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13]
y=str(list[0])

for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
    if list[i+1] == list[i]+1 :
        y+= '-' + str(list[i + 1])
    else:
        y+= ',' + str(list[i + 1])
print y


z= y.split(',')
outputString= ''
for i in z:
    p=i.split('-')
    if p[0] == p[len(p)-1]:
        outputString = outputString + str(p[0]) + str(',')
    else:
        outputString = outputString + str(p[0]) + str('-') + str(p[len(p) - 1]) + str(',')

outputString = outputString[:len(outputString) - 1]
print 'final ans: ',outputString
```

add these lines after your code.

Answer (score 2):

Since the other guy who posted this solution deleted his answer...

Here's a `O(n)` string building solution:

```
def stringify(lst):
    result = str(lst[0])
    end = None
    for index, num in enumerate(lst[1:]):
        if num - 1 == lst[index]:  # the slice shifts the index by 1 for us
            end = str(num)
        else:
            if end:
                result += '-' + end
                end = None
            result += ', ' + str(num)
    # Catch the last term
    if end:
        result += '-' + str(num)
    return result
```

See the [repl.it](https://repl.it/GZ3g/1)

Comment: This one is quite readable ! However output has the last index of the list twice.

Comment: @Yoshiki You're right, I fixed the bug and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most readable solution but gets the job done. One can first determine jumps in your data (jump = difference between two elements is greater than 1). Then you just loop through you original list and collect the respective elements and join them to a string.

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9])

# find indexes of jumps in your data
l_diff = np.where(np.diff(l) > 1)[0] + 1

# add one index which makes slicing easier later on
if l_diff[0] != 0:
    l_diff = np.insert(l_diff, 0, 0)

# add all the data which are groups of consecutive values
res = []    
for ix, i in enumerate(l_diff):
    try:
        sl = l[i:l_diff[ix + 1]]
        if len(sl) > 1:
            res.append([sl[0], sl[-1]])
        else:
            res.append(sl)
    # means we reached end of l_diff
    except IndexError:
        sl = l[i:]
        if len(sl) > 1:
            res.append([sl[0], sl[-1]])
        else:
            res.append(sl)


# join the data accordingly, we first have to convert integers to strings
res = ', '.join(['-'.join(map(str, ai)) for ai in res])
```

Then `res` is

```
'1-3, 6, 8-9'
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit shorter than the current answers but is still pretty readable.

There might be a nicer way to do it without building an object up with an explicit loop, but I couldn't think of one.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]

runs = [[str(L[0])]]

for first, second in zip(L, L[1:]):
    if second == first + 1:
        runs[-1].append(str(second))
    else:
        runs.append([str(second)])

result = ", ".join(["-".join(run) for run in runs])
```