# Get consecutive numbers in delimited format with a hyphen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to create a dictionary for generating numbers based on the first column. These numbers will be clubbed together based on the value given in Column ‘Type’. For eg: `Double` will have number like 2-3 to mean they're the set {2,3}, and `Three` will have 4-6 to mean they're the set {4,5,6}.

My dataframe should look like:

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Single | 1 |
| Double | 2-3 |
| Three | 4-6 |
| Four | 7-10 |
| Single | 11 |
| Four | 12-15 |
| Double | 16-17 |

I have not tried anything yet, as i do not know how to go about it. I was only able to generate the serial numbers like 1, 2, 3 for each row instead of the required output.
Not sure if Pandas or Numpy can solve such a problem

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841514/formatting-consecutive-numbers) but not sure how to utilise based on a dictionary as is required.

Comment: you posted the "required dataframe" - also post the input dataframe (it's also required)

Comment: If you haven't tried _anything_ yet, maybe start with that. Don't try to write the best code, just start by writing _any_ code: at the very least show the code you already talk about as having written in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {'Single':1,'Double':2,'Three':3,'Four':4}
(df['Type'].map(lambda x: [1]*d.get(x))
.explode()
.cumsum()
.astype(str)
.groupby(level=0)
.agg(lambda x: '-'.join([x.iloc[0],x.iloc[-1]] if len(x)>1 else x)))
```

or

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Type'].map(d))]
.assign(r = lambda x: np.arange(1,x.shape[0]+1).astype(str))
.groupby(level=0)['r']
.agg(lambda x: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(x.iloc[[0,-1]]))))
```

Output:

```
0        1
1      2-3
2      4-6
3     7-10
4       11
5    12-15
6    16-17
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.